# iOS - Whitespace appearing in iPhone 6 and 6+

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

While testing my app, some whitespace appears only in iPhone 6 and 6+.

**Some info about the setting**

My app storyboards are designed for iPhone 4s, I've added launch images in @3x (1242*2208) and @2x (750*1334) in images.xcassets **and** added an image named Default-568h@2x.png (this one was first 720*1280 and currently 1080*1920 for a reason I'm currently asking myself) in app files.

**Edit**: I have auto layout, use size classes options is disabled.

I don't have any problems with iPhone4s or iPhone5. I've already fixed the black bars at top and bottom of the app-thingy.

**Problem definition**

But when it comes to the iPhone6 and 6+, *poof*. App opens but has a white frame in bottom and right corner.

I'm adding some screenshots to show the problem thoroughly.

These two belong to iPhone 5.

[image: iPhone5-1]

Background is fading here, view is totally normal.

[image: iPhone5-2]

And now, for something completely different:
[image: iPhone6-1]

See those lines? Navigation bar and tableview stops there, but tab bar is functioning right.

[image: iPhone6-2]

In here, the switch is slided a bit. But the total view is not bad.

So, what did I miss?

Comment: Thanks to @Spacedust_ for fixing images in question. I was just looking how to fix them.

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that detail. Yes, I use auto layout but size classes option is disabled.

Comment: I think it may be the constraints set for the nav bar and the table view, as well as the switch. Check if those have any constraints regarding the superview

Comment: I didn't set any constraints before, but I choose some objects and used "Clear Constraints" option. And choose some other objects with "Reset to recommended Constraints" option just to see the difference.
Clearing didn't make any change, but recommended constraints seems to fix the issue (at least for now).

Comment: @J.C.Chaparro constraints fixed the edges, but other views are messed up.
Since I'm deploying this app for the range of iPhone4s to iPhone6+, I used constraints, but it appears that iOS7 and iOS8 handles constraints differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much thanks to @J.C.Chaparro for providing the starting line for me.

I'm adding an detailed answer for help others in the same situation.

There is what I did;

Added height and width constraints to wallpaper, only width constraints to custom-made navigation bars.

This will only result in fixed navigation bars, **not** totally screen-size adjusted texts or images.

You're going to have adjust them by yourselves, using constraints.
Use *reset recommended constraints* to your advantage, I fixed some pages using only this option.

But still, it has flaws. So, when you see some flaw caused by *recommended constraints* ; try to use only width constraints. That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues.

- First I had problems like your **first image**. The solution to that was to add proper LaunchImages *(.png files)*, their proper sizes are shown in warnings if they are wrong.
- Secondly I had the issue in the image where you painted a **red line**. The solution to this problem was to open the storyboard, click on the view controller *(main/initial View controller in my case)* and show the Attributes inspector, and finally select Size *(iPhone 4.7 inch in my case)* in Simulated metrics *(I had to adjust my layout)*.

I hope this helps.